# How long it takes the server to load a page with all it's content

Tags: php, load-time

I need to know how long it takes to load my website with all the necessary css and js files a browser would load. 
Is there an easy way to do this or I need to file_get_content all separately?

These calculations need to be in PHP and not on the client side.

Comment: You need to know this in PHP or can it be in any way? Chrome can show you this information in the developers tools.

Comment: The problem with doing this on the server side is that it has no real reflection of a users experience. The conditions on the client's side might be very different. Slower internet connection, old slow and bloated browsers...etc..

Comment: I know what you mean but I will use it in statistics for about 100 sites. How it varies among browsers is acceptable. I just need some number close to it.

Comment: The question should then be "How long does it take the SERVER to load a page"

Comment: You are right. How long does it take the SERVER to load a page with all the scripts.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with PHP alone. Nowadays many sites using Javascript to trigger the loading of other files. Without executing JS code you will likely miss some files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window onload event or if you use jQuery, you can use the ready function to send an AJAX request back to your server to let you know approximately when the page was fully loaded.

Comment: Thank you, it sounds like a way to go. But cron will be involved.

Comment: No problem - this is the only way I think is possible to test what you're asking programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to know is the total page load time of a particular webpage of your choice. You may either use the tools provideed by a browser such as `google chrome` or simply use a web service such as http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Please note that the results may slightly vary from one another. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. It isn't what I expected but it is OK in my case :)

Comment: @JaromírBaGricekNavara. Well What exactly do you expect. Please be specific as possible. :)

Comment: I just need to download a webpage with all js and css files and it would be close enough. I was really just hoping there is an easier way to find out than just download it all separately by file_get_contents.  Pingdom is great, but it's quite expensive in my case plus it looks jQuery based.